# Rails - Incorrect username/password notice appears on page when login link clicked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, notice

I'm having a problem with a notice appearing when it shouldn't. When I click a link in my app to login, it's flashing the 'Invalid username/password combination' notice, even though I haven't typed anything in. I understand why I'm getting the message - it's because when I click the link, I haven't typed in a matching username and password, so the error fires. But I'm not sure how to fix this. I want the error to appear when the user *does* type in the wrong combo, but not when the page first appears.

In the code, the 'user' refers to an admin, and the customer is a customer. I'm using the same login page for both types of people.

Also, what I'd really like is that when the user does type in the wrong combination, their email address will stay in the field so that they don't have to type it in again. How would I go about doing this?

Thanks!!

Here's the updated controller code:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :authorize
  def new
  end

 def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    customer = Customer.find_by_email(params[:email])

  if user and user.authenticate(params[:password])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to admin_url

  elsif customer and customer.authenticate(params[:password])
    session[:customer_id] = customer.id
    redirect_to customer_path(session[:customer_id]) 

  else
    render :new, notice: "Invalid email/password combination"
  end
 end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    session[:customer_id] = nil
    redirect_to store_url, notice: "Logged out"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the flash notice only when login parameters where sent with the request:

```
# ...
else
  flash[:notice] = "Invalid username/password combination" if params[:email] || params[:password]
  redirect_to login_url
end
```

Comment: This doesn't create a flash on the page - I've tried it with redirect_to and render, and both have the same result - any idea what's causing that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you wrap everything in `if params` and re`render` the view instead of redirecting to preserve the email.

```
if params
  if user ...
    ...
  elsif ...
    ...
  else
    render :new
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great for rendering the info they typed into the fields, but the 'Invalid email/password' notice isn't appearing when the incorrect login info is being entered. This is the line I've got: else
             render :new, notice: "Invalid email/password         combination"
    end - and I don't see why it's not working?

Comment: Be sure to put `flash[:notice] = 'Task failed to update.'` before render :new. It's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your last else statement with this:

```
else
  if params[:email] || params[:password]
    flash[:notice] = "Invalid username/password combination"
    redirect_to login_url
  end
end
```

That should do the trick. In regards to your question about the email address remaining in the field when the user enters an incorrect password, check this link: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916995/keep-form-fields-filled-after-an-error-ror/)

The general gist of the solution would be to use `'render'` instead of `'redirect_to'` in your code to reload the page.

Comment: If I use this with the last line being render :new, it takes me to the create view - any idea why?

Comment: Fixed that problem - I just needed to add an 'else' to the if statement above to redirect to the login url. However, the problem now is that when the user does correctly log in, they are given the 'invalid username etc.' error when they log in successfully.

Comment: That means that the else statement is running even though the authentication is  successful. Could you post your new code?