# select_day/year/month preset value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How I can preserve the value of [select_day](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-select_day) after validation error? I can set default value for it like this:

```
f.select_day 1, {prefix: 'user[birthdate]'}
```

But I can't do like this to set the value from the model:

```
f.select_day :birthdate, {prefix: 'user[birthdate]'}
```

error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `day' for :birthdate:Symbol)
```

*Is it possible or I need to get and set the value from params manually?*

model:

```
class User
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveRecord::AttributeAssignment
  attr_accessor :birthdate
  def self.build(request, params = {})
    u = self.new
    u.assign_attributes(params)
    u
  end
end
```

controller:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
end

def create
  @user = User.build(params[:user])
end
```

view:

```
= form_for @user do |f|
  f.select_day 1, {prefix: 'user[birthdate]'}
  f.select_month 1, {prefix: 'user[birthdate]'}
  f.select_year 1990, {prefix: 'user[birthdate]'}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916995/keep-form-fields-filled-after-an-error-ror

Comment: @HasanIqbalAnik this doesn't work as I said before.

Comment: @freemanoid Look at your error man. The select_day is expecting a date ([docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-select_day)). My guess is that a numeric is being stored in that spot. Can you confirm?

Comment: @screenmutt but how I can get the date from the model? I want to have **one** view for new and create (in case of validation error) action

Comment: @freemanoid Can you post the entire form code? I'll put together an example of usage when I can.

Comment: Where is `user[birthdate]` defined?

Comment: Tricky question. I tried an answer, but it wasn't right

Comment: @RichPeck ```user[birthdate]``` is just an attribute name in form.

Comment: I think your problem is with `user[birthdate]` but I can't work out exactly how you're creating the param

Comment: @RichPeck if I remove the custom prefix than date params will be in ```day```, ```month```, ```year``` but I want it to be like ```user[birthdate][day]```, ```user[birthdate][month]```, ```user[birthdate][year]```

Comment: Okay! Do you have birthdate as a column in the model?

Comment: @RichPeck, I have an accessor, please look at the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check into the documentation for [select_day](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/select_month#238--prefix-option) (and _month and _year) you'll see that the methods *normally* accept a date for their first parameter.  They also accept an integer as you've chosen to do but that is a decidedly alternate implementation.

Be that as it may, I'd suggest a couple of small changes.  First, I'd strongly consider setting a default birthdate for the User class along these lines.

```
class User
  attr_accessor :birthdate

  def initialize()
    @birthdate = Date.new 1990, 1, 1
    super
  end

  ...
end
```

Then your forms can make use of the User#birthdate accessor in both new and edit views.

```
= form_for @user do |f|
  = f.select_day @user.birthdate, prefix: 'user[birthdate]'
  = f.select_month @user.birthdate, prefix: 'user[birthdate]'
  = f.select_year @user.birthdate, prefix: 'user[birthdate]'
```

Answer (score 2):

**Approach 1 (Hacky):**

What you're asking is multi-parameter assignment which is done by [assign_multiparameter_attributes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeAssignment/assign_multiparameter_attributes).

Change your form to look similar to this.

```
= select_day @user.birthdate, prefix: "user", field_name: "birthdate(3i)"
= select_month @user.birthdate, prefix: "user", field_name: "birthdate(2i)"
= select_year @user.birthdate, prefix: "user", field_name: "birthdate(1i)"
```

`assign_multiparameter_attributes` expects the column type to be known to set the value. For that to work, you will have to have a method called `column_for_attribute(name)`

```
attr_accessor :birthdate

def column_for_attribute(name)
  return ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.new(:birthdate, nil, "date") if name.to_sym == :birthdate
end
```

This is why using `ActiveRecord` modules without DB is a bad idea.

**Approach 2 (Enhance ActiveModel):**

Have a look at [this](https://coderwall.com/p/eqwiqg). It attempts to create an `BaseModel` which handles assigning dates.

**Approach 3 (Custom code):**

If you don't wanna use the gem, then the way would be to introduce three attributes `(day, month, year)`  in `User` and have a method called `birthdate` which creates `Date` object from those three.

If you have similar requirements at many places, I would suggest to enhance ActiveModel (Approach 2). But If you've this requirement at only one place go with Approach 3.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the full select [select_datetime](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-select_datetime) option? This would automatically generate all the fields necessary to plug in the date.

You could also look at using something like [JQueryUI datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) which would allow you to use a normal text field and provide a nice little pop-up for picking a date, while also allowing the user to type in a date if they like.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try to do:

```
= f.select_day f.object.birthday, {prefix: 'user[birthdate]'}
```

Comment: actually no ... yes ... now I see the bug ... but main message was about "f.object.birthday" .... because I don't see the difference between my code and yours f.select_day 1, {prefix: 'user[birthdate]'} ... it's the same.