# Keep data form after submit using sessions in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, devise, simple-form

I added custom field to devise registration form : radio button and select list the problem I have is that if there is an error while validating data (for example the user wrote the password wrong) I will be redirected to registration form , the custom fields will loose the data.
The example is explained in those 2 pictures :

[Before submitting data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLXbz.png)

[After submitting data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wukfR.png)

Like in the two pictures the user should click again the radio button to select a value , normally it should be saved in session by devise.

new.html.erb

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>

    <div class="form-inputs">
      <%= f.input :user_type, as: :radio_buttons, collection: %w(personnal professional), checked: 'personnal' %>
      <%= f.input :name, required: true %>
      <%= f.input :city,as: :select,required: true,%>
      <%= f.input :email, required: true %>
      <%= f.input :password, required: true, hint: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @minimum_password_length) %>
      <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up" %>
    </div> <% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name,:city,:user_type,:phone])
  end
end
```

User.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

I found a solution in stackoverflow here but I coudn't make it work with devise I generated already devise controllers but the solution dosen't work for me.
[Keep form fields filled after an error (RoR)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916995/keep-form-fields-filled-after-an-error-ror)

Comment: Please post the related code, controller/view etc.

Comment: @31piy I posted the code related to the problem. For devise controller I didn't add any code because I don't know what to add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with one that you gave a link to. You explicitly set the value of the `user_type` parameter in the form, but you shouldn't.

Change

```
<%= f.input :user_type, as: :radio_buttons, collection: %w(personnal professional), checked: 'personnal' %>
```

To

```
<%= f.input :user_type, as: :radio_buttons, collection: %w(personnal professional) %>
```

The parameter is going to be set automatically, depending on `resource`. When you submit the form, the parameter should stay as it was set.

If you want to set a default value, you can do it like this:

```
<%= f.input :user_type, as: :radio_buttons, collection: %w(personnal professional), checked: resource.user_type || 'personnal' %>
```

Not the best way, but the simplest.

Comment: thank you , is there another way to make the radio button checked by default?

Comment: Edited the answer. Is that what you want?

Comment: Thank you so much I was searching for that behavior for 3 days ! :)